# openright in report

Tags: double-sided, report

I would like to start my document with the title page on the right hand side. I am using the `openright` option:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}
```

But now every chapter starts on the right. I just want the title page to be on the right side and no blank pages should be inserted in the document. is there a way to do this with the report document class?

Comment: Why using `openright`, then?

Answer (score -1):

That's what the openright option does.

Using just what you gave as baseline, my document starts on a right page. Layout rule is, that the inner margin of the printed report/book/article/.. should have the same width as the outer margin. The inner margin appears smaller in pdf (single-page view), because left+right side combined make up the inner margin.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
   \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

looks like this in two-page view

[image]

Comment: Well, the margin for the binding is inverted in your screenshot, the large margin should be on the the middle.